# Nested variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a variable `client: client1` and I want to use it to fetch multiple facts into a template like below.

`"{{ hostvars[{{ client }}][ansible_default_ipv4][address] }}"`

`"{{ hostvars[{{ client }}][ansible_hostname] }}"`

`"{{ hostvars[{{ client }}][ansible_fqdn] }}"`

I have tried removing the braces, using a dictionary[key] in place of client but couldn't figure out. What is the right usage here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer is: `"{{ hostvars[client]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"`

Comment: how can this be done. ```region: 1 dev1_ips: 1,2  {{ dev[region]_ips }} ```. This is not working